# Three different time values when using traceroute

Tags: networking, router, troubleshooting, time, traceroute

I'm learning networking troubleshooting and noticed how there are three different time values outputted for every hop when using traceroute, *what do they mean*? (The left CLI in the image is a router and the right is a Windows CLI)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three requests are made for each hop, and the times represent the round-trip time for each request.  In your first example, the third request to hop number 3 took far longer than the other two.

You're likely to see bigger disparities for more distant hops as there are more factors that can affect round-trip times.

Comment: Ahaa! Do you BTW know any flag or something you can use together with traceoroute/tracert to at the end of the output get min/avg/max times? @flup

Comment: I don't, but stats like that would be pretty meaningless.  You might be better off looking at the stats at the end of a `ping` run.

Comment: Of course, I just got them mixed up ;) @flup

Comment: If you want something with more stats than traceroute, look at MTR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_%28software%29